# Problems import csv indexed by dates

Tags: r, csv, xts

I am trying to import a csv file with OHLC data to use with quantmod. I keep getting errors with the date column.

here is the error:

```
Error in read.zoo(file2, sep = ",", format = "%Y-%m-%d h:m:s.S", header = TRUE,  : index has 4706262 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3...
```

what I am using to import the data:

```
zz <- read.zoo(file2, sep = ",",format="%Y-%m-%d h:m:s.S", 
header=TRUE,index.column=1,colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",5)))
head(zz)

xx<- as.xts(zz)
```

I tried looking at [docs](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) but it didn't help me.

Here is an example from my csv file

```
time,open,high,low,close,volume,
2005-01-02 10:29:00.0,1.356,1.356,1.356,1.356,1,
2005-01-02 10:38:00.0,1.356,1.356,1.356,1.356,1,
2005-01-02 10:51:00.0,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1,
2005-01-02 10:52:00.0,1.3565,1.3565,1.3565,1.3565,1,
2005-01-02 10:55:00.0,1.3568,1.3568,1.3568,1.3568,1,
2005-01-02 10:57:00.0,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1,
2005-01-02 11:04:00.0,1.3569,1.3569,1.3569,1.3569,1,
2005-01-02 11:07:00.0,1.357,1.357,1.3569,1.3569,2,
```

Comment: With such things, I always prefer to input the csv in raw form (using `read.csv`), then convert the date-like strings into dates using the `lubridate` package.  Converting to `xts` should be straightforward after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` (see `?strptime`) and `colClasses` (see `?read.table`) arguments in the question are wrong and some of the arguments specified there are unnecessary.

**1)** The following shorter code should do. In the time it ignores the part after the dot but that is zero anyways so it does not matter.  If there are non-zero digits after the dot in some rows in the real data then see the help file mentioned above for the correct percent codes to use in `format`.

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", colClasses = c(X = "NULL"))
```

giving:

```
                      open   high    low  close volume
2005-01-02 10:29:00 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560      1
2005-01-02 10:38:00 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560      1
2005-01-02 10:51:00 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567      1
2005-01-02 10:52:00 1.3565 1.3565 1.3565 1.3565      1
2005-01-02 10:55:00 1.3568 1.3568 1.3568 1.3568      1
2005-01-02 10:57:00 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567      1
2005-01-02 11:04:00 1.3569 1.3569 1.3569 1.3569      1
2005-01-02 11:07:00 1.3570 1.3570 1.3569 1.3569      2
```

(We have used `text = Lines` to keep this self contained -- `Lines` is given in the Note below -- you would replace that with your filename as in the question.)

**1a)** Even shorter would be the following.

```
read.csv.zoo(text = Lines, colClasses = c(X = "NULL"))
```

**2)** Alternately, this two-step approach is particularly simple:

```
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)[-7]
read.zoo(DF)
```

**3)**

```
library(zoo)

read.zoo(text = Lines, read = function(...) read.csv(...)[-7])
```

**Note:** The input is:

```
Lines <- "
time,open,high,low,close,volume,
2005-01-02 10:29:00.0,1.356,1.356,1.356,1.356,1,
2005-01-02 10:38:00.0,1.356,1.356,1.356,1.356,1,
2005-01-02 10:51:00.0,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1,
2005-01-02 10:52:00.0,1.3565,1.3565,1.3565,1.3565,1,
2005-01-02 10:55:00.0,1.3568,1.3568,1.3568,1.3568,1,
2005-01-02 10:57:00.0,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1.3567,1,
2005-01-02 11:04:00.0,1.3569,1.3569,1.3569,1.3569,1,
2005-01-02 11:07:00.0,1.357,1.357,1.3569,1.3569,2,"
```

**Update:** At the time this was originally posted some of the commands here required the development version of zoo but that is now out so they all work with regular zoo on CRAN.

Comment: So Lines needs to be the raw text of the csv file?

Comment: Alright, I should have been more clear, I need to convert it into an xts, which is time-based, so I need to format the output as such. so I can do: xx<- as.xts(zz)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a file named `‘testFile.csv’` and in your working directory, you can do the following to get the asked for `xts-object`:

```
testFile <- read.csv("testFile.csv", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",5),NULL))

>as.xts(testFile[,2:6],order.by = as.POSIXct(testFile[,1]))

                      open   high    low  close volume
2005-01-02 10:29:00 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560      1
2005-01-02 10:38:00 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560 1.3560      1
2005-01-02 10:51:00 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567      1
2005-01-02 10:52:00 1.3565 1.3565 1.3565 1.3565      1
2005-01-02 10:55:00 1.3568 1.3568 1.3568 1.3568      1
2005-01-02 10:57:00 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567 1.3567      1
2005-01-02 11:04:00 1.3569 1.3569 1.3569 1.3569      1
2005-01-02 11:07:00 1.3570 1.3570 1.3569 1.3569      2
```